# python print next word in a file

Tags: python

I have a error over the code here to print the next word/string that is contained on the file

```
for i in cursor.fetchall():
    keywords.append(i[0])

with open('qwer.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for key in keywords:
            if key in line:
                line = line.split(". ")
                for j in range(len(line)):  <----error(str obj not callable)
                    print line[key(j+1)]    <----error
```

Comment: print your `line` and see what it is.

Comment: You're calling `range` and `len`; sure you haven't shadowed them?Or is that error the next line? Full traceback would help.

Comment: my line "i have a pen and pencil" my output has to be "pen" since my keyword consists of "a"

Comment: yeah error is also over next line

Comment: can you give an example of the content of the file?

Comment: the error is probably in `key(j+1)`. so will you please let me know what is `key`

Comment: try `key[j+1]` you cannot call a string

Comment: the key is:'a',so it has to print next letter after 'a' .the file content is 'i have a pen and pencil' here after 'a' is 'pen' so the output has to be 'pen'

Comment: seems like you need `line[line.find(key)+1]` instead of `key(j+1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print line[key(j+1)]
```

Is an attempt to call `key` with the single argument `j+1`. However, `key` is a string so can't be called. I think you meant to use the index `key[j+1]`, but that won't be an integer so the attempt to index `line` with it will fail.

I think what you want is:

```
line[line.index(key) + 1]
```

Really you should be checking `key in line` *after* the split:

```
with open('qwer.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.split()
        for key in keywords:
            if key in line:
                print line[line.index(key)+1]
```

Comment: it works but is prints 5 times like :pen pen pen pen pen

Comment: Well you don't still need the `for` loop! Updated with implementation.